# Unison sync across more than 2 computers

Tags: backup, unison

I am currently using `Unison` across 2 computers (`server` and `laptop`). I need to create another connection where I can timely backup my data from server.

`laptop <--> server -> backup`

Here the connection to `backup` from `server` can be unidirectional. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common thing to do. When setting up Unison across multiple machines, you should prefer a star topology. So if you can, you should run another instance of Unison, along with any backup-related scrips, on your machine where you are storing your backups. It should look about the same as your setup on your laptop (depending on where your backups are being stored).